# Canon RAW (CR2) codec for Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-explorer, thumbnails, camera-raw

I have a Canon DSLR, and I shoot in RAW. I have no problem viewing and editing the pictures using Picasa or Lightroom, but I would like to have the pictures thumbnails in Windows Explorer, and to be able to quickly view them in the explorer.

Do you guys know where I could get the codec (for free) ? I found a few codec packs that include it, but I feel like I should not have to pay for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to spend $10, then you might want to try the [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/). It works like an absolute charm on my Windows 7 32-bit install, and is rated to run just fine on x64 too.

[This page](http://www.microsoft.com/prophoto/downloads/codecs.aspx#canon) probably doesn't help, as it offers 32-bit codecs only.

Otherwise, you can try to *get around* the problem by using an [alternative, fast image viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I really would like to have the thumbnails in windows explorer. The viewer itself is not really the issue, as I use Picasa anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Since July last year (according to [this  answer on the sister site for photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/14369/21)), there are now [CODECs available for x64 from Microsoft free of charge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26829&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20MicrosoftDownloadCenter%20%28Microsoft%20Download%20Center%29#tm) - these also work for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to modify the thumbnailing codecs built into W7. Windows thumbnailer is not the same as other codecs you can install.

If you discover a way, please post it.

Comment: There are codecs, but not for x64.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, however [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/) has a [Raw Digital Camera plug-in](http://resource.dopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=10514) for previewing RAW files, plus it's a brilliant Windows Explorer replacement.  The plug-in will also pull out all the metadata associated with the RAW images - good for organisation.

Here a preview;

[image: Directory Opus previewing RAW files]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem with seeing CR2 files in Windows explorer. Only thing I did was installing Digital Photo Professional from [Canon support site](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/) or [Windows codec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20MicrosoftDownloadCenter%20%28Microsoft%20Download%20Center%29#tm).