# Is there a free NEF codec for Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: images, codec, camera-raw

Is there a free NEF codec for Windows 7 64-bit?

NEF is Nikon's RAW picture file format. The NEF codec allows you to view NEF files in Windows Explorer as any other natively supported image formats such as JPEG and TIFF. If I understand correctly Nickon only distributes the 32-bit version of the codec.

Is this true? If so - is there an free alternative for Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/173801/canon-raw-cr2-codec-for-windows-7-x64

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft has published a camera codec pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) that supports both 32- and 64-bit Windows 7.

From the page:

> The Microsoft Camera Codec Pack enables the viewing of a variety of device-specific file formats in Windows Live Photo Gallery as well as other software that is based on Windows Imaging Codecs (WIC).

It supports the following Nikon cameras:

> ...
>   **Nikon**: 1 J1, 1 J2, 1 V1, Coolpix P6000, Coolpix P7000, Coolpix P7100,
>   D1H, D2H, D2Hs, D2X, D2Xs, D3, D3s, D3X, D4, D40, D40x, D50, D60, D70,
>   D70s, D80, D90, D100, D200, D300, D300s, D700, D800, D800E, D3000,
>   D3100, D3200, D5000, D5100, D7000

Answer (score 1):

No NEF codec but a viewer that can display them, unfortunately not free, you can search google for an older version that is free

http://mansurovs.com/free-nikon-raw-nef-codec-for-64-bit-vista-or-windows-7

Or try Irfanview with plugins

http://www.irfanview.com/

I can find no free plugin codec for 64bit

I did find one for a small fee, it is shareware and will install to test. It says it is for 64bit
http://www.brothersoft.com/nikon-raw-nef-codec-281179.html

> The 32 bit MSI and 64 bit MSI files that are included in the installer are available for administrators who need more installations options than are available in the Default installer. On 64 bit platforms you should install both 32 bit and 64 bit codecs if you need to support 32 bit applications that use WIC.

.
.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old. But these days the Nikon software also supports 64 bit. So the problem might be solved by [downloading the NEF Codec](http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/) from the Nikon itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know this is an ancient thread. Today we find ourselves in September 2022. However there are users out there that still use Windows 7. The link provided by @rokdd takes you to Nikon's current download page for the Nikon NEF codec which no longer supports Windows 7.
I did manage to find a Nikon download "archive" of sorts. It contains software, firmware and drivers from 2009 to present. The url (English) for the last Nikon Windows 7 NEF codec needs to be modified slightly and can be found at

https://downloadcenter-origin(dot)nikonimglib(dot)com/en/update/index/2016(dot)html

I hope anyone ending up on this thread finds the link useful.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, I was searching now for related stuff and found that the last answer of this old question was 2 hours ago... It's really coincident.

In any case, it won't work in all setups. For example, I need to open nef files from a D3500 on Windows 7 and the first version of NEF codecs that allows it (in theory), is 1.31.0. So, according with maxxrnb's official link (thank you, I was only finding 3rd party servers), is from 2017, supporting only Windows 8 and 10, and still no mention D3500. So in my case there are a lack of compatibility. It seems that Nikon are so extreme making the software obsolete.

Anyway, I will try 1.30 (compatible with Win 7), and hopefully will open D3500 NEFs...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144684)